# Passing datetime64[ns] from pandas' data frame as an argument to a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to create an additional column in a data frame to show the number of network days (excluding custom holidays) between two dates. I'm using a function to which I'm trying to pass dates from `df`'s columns as arguments, but I can't make it work.

Below is my code (I'm using two made-up holidays in the given set):

```
from networkdays import networkdays
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

public_holidays_list = [dt.date(2021, 1, 6), dt.date(2021, 1, 7)]
public_holidays = set(public_holidays_list)

def working_days(start, end, holidays):
    days = networkdays.Networkdays(start, end, holidays)
    working_days = len(days.networkdays())
    return working_days
```

The formula itself works fine:

```
print(working_days(dt.date(2021, 1, 4), dt.date(2021, 1, 8), public_holidays))
```

> 3

Minimal data frame with the `dtypes` I'm working on:

```
d = {'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'Start_Date': [dt.date(2021, 1, 4), dt.date(2021, 1, 11)], 'End_Date': [dt.date(2021, 1, 8), dt.date(2021, 1, 15)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
```

When I'm trying the below way...

```
df['Working_Days'] = working_days(df['Start_Date'], df['End_Date'])
```

...I'm getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

I've also tried to use `numpy`:

```
df['Working_Days'] = np.vectorize(working_days)(df['Start_Date'], df['End_Date'])
```

I got an error as well:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'days'

Could you point me in the right direction?

**EDIT: The correct answer to my problem is @Kris's last comment.**

**IMPORTANT!** Although the `lambda` doesn't return any errors, it takes `public_holidays` into consideration correctly in 2 scenarios:

A) The elements of `public_holidays` are of class `datetime.date` and `df`'s dates are of class `object` (I got this by removing `pd.to_datetime()` lines from the code).

B) The `public_holidays` is of type `list` (created from an Excel table via `public_holidays = df_ph['Date'].tolist()`), its elements are of class `Timestamp` and `pd.to_datetime()` lines are not removed from the code above (making dates in `df` `datetime64[ns]`).

Comment: Look up [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). For example, `df['Working_Days'] = df.apply(lambda x: working_days(x.Start_Date, x.End_Date), axis=1)` might work.

Comment: ```@Kris```, it is now calculating the days, but without taking the public holidays into consideration. I've updated the function with the third argument - can you tell me how I can pass it to ```lambda```, as it's from "outside" of the data frame?

Comment: Add .dt to each of your arguments

Comment: @Witherfield you should be able to just pass it as normal, e.g. `df.apply(lambda x: working_days(x.Start_Date, x.End_Date, public_holidays), axis=1)`. I'd write up a full answer but I can't use `networkdays`.

Comment: @Kris, it works indeed, thanks! Could you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, use `.apply`:

```
df['Working_Days'] = df.apply(lambda x: working_days(x.Start_Date, x.End_Date, public_holidays), axis=1)
```